# Iteratively fill missing values

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have a data frame with one column completely filled and the other one partially filled. I would like like to fill up the [na](/questions/tagged/na)s in the second column with this formula: `col3 = col1*lag(col2)`

When I'm using mutate, it's iterating once. I prefer using a [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) function since I will need to apply this function over a larger sample.

Here is the data frame

```
dd <- tibble::tribble(~col1, ~col2,
  1.1127493, 34533.98,
  0.9432176, 32573.06,
  0.9130100, 29758.64,
  0.6593648, 19621.80,
  0.9222222, 18095.66,
  0.7349398, 13299.22,
  0.9836066, 13081.20,
  0.8518519,       NA,
  1.0000000,       NA,
  1.0000000,       NA,
  1.0000000,       NA,
  1.0000000,       NA)
```

Comment: What exactly does your mutate call look like?

Comment: @MrFlick  df %>%mutate(col3 = col1*lag(col2))

Comment: What would you like to happen when col2 has more than one NA in a row, that is, when `is.na(lag(col2)) == TRUE` ?

Comment: @Jordo82 Ideally what I want is once I compute col3 as col1*lag(col2), the last value of col3 should fill up the first NA in col2 and the process iterated again. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @No.Clue I'm sure there's a better way, but the only way I've found to deal with recursive columns like that is with a loop.  `for(i in 2:nrow(df)){df$col3[i] <- df$col1[i] * ifelse(is.na(df$col2[i-1]), df$col3[i-1], df$col2[i-1])}`

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to understand the procedure you have in mind and why is it guaranteed to terminate. May be you can specify your procedure in some more detail. In the meantime, I created a procedure close the one you are asking for, to serve you as a guide, so that you can write your own solution.

```
iter_func <- function(c1, c2){
  c3 <- c1 + dplyr::lag(c2)
  na_pos <- which(is.na(c3))
  non_na_pos <- which(!is.na(c3))

  while(length(na_pos)){
    c3[na_pos[1]] <- c3[non_na_pos[length(non_na_pos)]]
    c3 <- c1 + c3

    na_pos <- which(is.na(c3))
    non_na_pos <- which(!is.na(c3))
  }

  c3
}

dd %>% dplyr::mutate(col3 = iter_func(col1, col2))
```

HTH